# Cast issues between generic list and CollectionDataContract

Tags: c#, wcf, type-conversion, datacontractserializer

I have the following collection contract defined:

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "Centres")]
public class Centres : List<Centre>
{}
```

and the following operation contract defined to return this collection

```
public Model.Centres GetCentres()
{
     List<Centre> allCentres = (from c in Model.Centre.GetCentres()
                                    where c.Visible == true
                                    select c).ToList();

     return allCentres
}
```

But when I run the code I receive an ExplicitCastException. So as far as I can see I'm trying to cast a list of centres (List) into my collection 'Centres' which itself derives from List. Is this possible or by deriving a new object am I creating a new type of list that won't work in this way.

My current work around for this problem is to declare a new instance of Centres and copy all centres into it using a foreach.

Comment: There is no ExplicitCastException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `Centres` "is a" `List<Centre>`, `List<Centre>` is not a `Centres`.

Despite `Centres` having no implementation it is still a sub-class of `List<Centre>`, you could extend your `Centres` class to have an implicit conversion operator or, perhaps add a constructor to Centres that takes a `List<Centre>` as a parameter.

Try changing `Centres` to somthing like ...

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "Centres")] 
public class Centres : List<Centre> 
{
    public static implicit operator Centres(List<Centre> l)
    {
        Centres newCentres = new Centres();
        newCentres.AddRange(l);
        return newCentres;
    }
}
```

Then it will allow implicit conversion from `List<Centre>.`

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying wont work.

If possible you should consider refactoring Centres to a *has a* `List<Centre>` more than *is a* relationship or at least define a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<Centre>`

This way you would be able to write:

```
Centres allCentres = new Centres(from c in Model.Centres.GetCentres()
                                   where c.Visible == true
                                   select c);
```

Of course it all depends on your specific situation where this might not be a valid solution.

Comment: @Jon Free, this is like my suggested alternative, of extending the contructor and, in terms of OO design, probably more correct. The implicit operator creates a potentially false, but useful, "is a" relationship.

Comment: If the constructor defenition were included I'd be inclined to +1

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create your own implementation of the `IList<T>` interface that wraps an IList. 
It takes more code, but will not be as slow as to copy all the objects:

```
  [CollectionDataContract(Name = "Centres")]
  public class Centres : IList<Centre>
    {
        private IList<Centre> _inner;
        private IList<Centre> Inner
        {
            get
            {
                if (_inner == null)
                    _inner = new List<Centre>();
                return _inner;
            }
        }
        public Centres(List<Centre> items)
        {
            _inner = items;
        }

        #region IList<Centre> Members

        public int IndexOf(Centre item)
        {
            return Inner.IndexOf(item);
        }

        public void Insert(int index, Centre item)
        {
            Inner.Insert(index, item);
        }

        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            Inner.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        public Centre this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return Inner[index];
            }
            set
            {
                Inner[index] = value;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region ICollection<Centre> Members

        public void Add(Centre item)
        {
            Inner.Add(item);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            Inner.Clear();
        }

        public bool Contains(Centre item)
        {
            return Inner.Contains(item);
        }

        public void CopyTo(Centre[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            Inner.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return Inner.Count; }
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return Inner.IsReadOnly; }
        }

        public bool Remove(Centre item)
        {
            return Inner.Remove(item);
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable<Centre> Members

        public IEnumerator<Centre> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return Inner.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable Members

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return Inner.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```